# Display the name entered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm learning JavaScript/HTML, and I need help to adjust the JS script function so that when the user clicks "submit" it will display the name that the user enters.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Names</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" rel="script" src="js/scripts.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>

  <label for="name">Your Name:</label>
  <input id="name" name="name" type="text"/> 

  <input id="submit-button" name="submit-button" type="submit" value="Submit"/>

  <h3>Result</h3>
  <div id="output">
            Form not submitted yet.
  </div>

<script>

function DisplayName(){
  document.getElementById('submit-btn').innerHTML = 
  document.getElementById("name").value;
  }
  console.log("Your name is: " + name);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems you already know how to get the name. Why not store that in the variable `name` you try to use before it exists?

Answer (score 0):

We can make a couple adjustments and get this working just fine. The common method would be to add a click event listener to your button that once clicked will trigger a function.

Let's add this to your button: `onclick="displayName()` , note I am writing the function in camelCase. This is a good practice for js functions. Here's how your button looks now:

```
<input id="submit-button" name="submit-button" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="displayName()"/>
```

Next let's do the javascript. We can keep it all in one simple function, the `displayName()` function.

```
function displayName(){
    var name= document.getElementById("name").value;
    console.log('Your name is: ' + name);  
}
```

First, this gets the value of the "name" id, then this will log it to the console.

If you want to enhance this slightly, you can also make a few adjustments to the js to display the name in the output `id` tag you created. Here's how your final work might look.

```js
function showName(){
    var name= document.getElementById("name").value;
   
    document.getElementById("output").innerText = name;        
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Names</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" rel="script" src="js/scripts.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <label for="name">Your name: </label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
  <input id="submit-button" name="submit-button" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="showName()" />

  <h3>Result</h3>
  <div id="output">
    Form not submitted yet.
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried it but the result just shows up for a second and then disappears?

Comment: you should prevent the default action of the submit button.

Comment: @supernova_97 Lal is correct , it is disappearing because the default of a form is to submit data. So change the js to the following should work: 
```function showName(e){ 
   e.preventDefault();
   var name= document.getElementById("name").value;
   document.getElementById("output").innerText = name;        
}```